# How to create list of urls from csv file to iterate?

Tags: python, list, loops, web-scraping

I am working on a webscrape code, he work fine, now I want replace the url, with a CSV file who containt thousand of url, it's like this :

```
url1
url2
url3
.
.
.urlX
```

my first line web scrape code is a basic :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from csv import writer

url= "HERE THE URL FROM EACH LINE OF THE CSV FILE"
page = requests.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

how can i do for tell to python, to use the urls from the CSV, i think to do a dico, but i dont very know how i can do that, anyone have a solution please ? i know it's seams very simple for you, but it will be very usefull for me.

Comment: Is there more than one column in the CSV or is this just a list of URLs? If the latter, a simple read of the file would do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is just a list of urls, you don't really need the `csv` module. But here is a solution assuming the url is in column 0 of the file. You want a csv *reader*, not writer, and then its a simple case of iterating the rows and taking action.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv

with open("url-collection.csv", newline="") as fileobj:
    for row in csv.reader(fileobj):
        # TODO: add try/except to handle errors
        url = row[0]
        page = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: thank for your answer, but i get the error =: with open("dicotest.csv", end="") as fileobj:
TypeError: 'end' is an invalid keyword argument for open()

Comment: Oops, I always get that one wrong. Why didn't they call that parameter "end"?! Fixed.

Comment: thanks for helping me, i did the modif, but now, it's tell : No connection adapters were found for {url!r} , the csv is simple row 0, and the like are simple

Comment: thanks it's work fine just added : encoding='utf-8-sig'

Comment: @OrochimaruSama - that link didn't work but it seems like you have a problem with the data in the text file. "{url!r}" looks like something trying to print a python f-string, but forgetting the leading `f` -  `f"{url!r}`. That would show the python "repr" of the string (including leading and trailing quotes) so even if it was fixed, it likely would still have a problem with those extra characters.